# How to make force:navigateToSObject to open record in new tab

Tags: javascript, lightning, lightning-experience

Is there any way to make  force:navigateToSObject event to open sObject in new tab?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, You can navigate to new tab using-

```
<aura:handler event="force:navigateToSObject" action="{!c.navigateToRecord}"/>

navigateToRecord : function(component , event, helper){
    window.open('/' + event.getParam('recordId'));  
},
```

Comment: From where do you fire this event?

Comment: From a custom lightning component.

Comment: You fire it and catch it in the same component. Probably be a good idea to cancel the event too

Comment: I think you also need to add `'_blank'` as the second param to `window.open()`

Comment: I knew the record Id, so when I directly used window.open('/' +recordId) it works. So is it OK to skip the navigate standard event?

Comment: It will work in both the cases. window.open('/' + event.getParam('recordId'),"_blank");

Comment: Salesforce poo poo's on the practice https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_supported_html_tags_a.htm , but it works. so Im using it for the moment.

Answer (score 5):

Since Salesforce suggests not using [hard-coded or dynamic URLs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_supported_html_tags_a.htm), I would recommend using the more reliable [lightning:navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation) to open a new tab in Salesforce. I struggled with solving this at first, so here is my working solution. Hope it helps.

.cmp file:

```
//include this anywhere in your .cmp file
<lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
```

controller.js :

```
//call your method/action
onClick: function(cmp, event, helper){
    var navService = cmp.find("navService");
    var pageReference = {    
       "type": "standard__recordPage", //example for opening a record page, see bottom for other supported types
       "attributes": {
       "recordId": recordId, //place your record id here that you wish to open
       "actionName": "view"
        }
    }

    navService.generateUrl(pageReference)
    .then($A.getCallback(function(url) {
      console.log('success: ' + url); //you can also set the url to an aura attribute if you wish
      window.open(url,'_blank'); //this opens your page in a seperate tab here
    }), 
    $A.getCallback(function(error) {
      console.log('error: ' + error);
    }));
}
```

According to the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm), pageReference supports opening:

- Lightning Component (must implement lightning:isUrlAddressable)
- Knowledge Article
- Login Page
- Named Page
- Navigation Item
- Page Object
- Page Record
- Page Record
- Relationship Page
- Web Page

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has problem with redirection to Process Instance Step, this worked for me

```
                const navService = component.find("navService");

                const processInstanceStepReference = {
                    type: 'standard__recordPage',
                    attributes: {
                        recordId: processInstanceStep.Id,
                        objectApiName: 'ProcessInstanceStep',
                        actionName: 'view'
                    }
                };

           const url = navService.generateUrl(processInstanceStepReference);
           navService.generateUrl(processInstanceStepReference)
           window.location.replace(url);
```

This prevents opening Process Instance Step as subtab for Process Instance Work Item.